# how can a specify header is in which table?

Tags: mysql

suppose i have three table with names : broker,man and  coach.

i want to know that for example 'name' field

is in which table.

how can realize it?

Comment: Can you elaborate why you need this? One usually knows the table's schema. What is your use case?

Comment: i read data from mysql and save it in a jtable(in java).

i want when i click on a specify row and colum and edit it

my databese has updated.

but a dont a field is in which table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strange question indeed.

```
select column_name,table_name 
from information_schema.columns
where table_schema = 'your_db' and table_name in ('broker','man','coach') and column_name = 'name'
```